# In which cases a method call succeeds?

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby expression `a.foo`, which calls method `foo` on receiver `a`, which of the following conditions affects whether the call succeeds?

1. `a` responds to the foo method.
2. `a`'s class, or one of its superclasses or included modules, implements method_missing in a way that handles the foo method.
3. `a` is an instance of a class, rather than the class itself.
4. `a` has the correct type.

Comment: Are you giving multiple choice for guys here?

Comment: @user1729711: It looks a bit like a quiz question, you know, quiz style multiple choice questions are frowned upon on StackOverflow :)

Comment: It actually is a quiz question from an online edx course..

Answer (score 4):

From given options the following conditions affects if the call succeeds

```
 - a responds to the foo method.    

 - a's class, or one of its superclasses or included modules, implements
       method_missing in a way that handles the foo method.
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, every object is an instance of some class. Classes themselves are instances of the `Class` class, and `Class` itself is a subclass of the `Module` class.

Any object responds to the instance methods defined by its class or its singleton class (which is automatically created when you add methods on the fly), and all the ancestor classes / modules. and all the ancestors (including modules).

If the object does not respond to the method sent to it, then **if** `method_missing` method has been defined for it, it is executed.

Nothing here ensures that the call will succeed. Any method or library may raise an exception during the execution of either the original method or the `method_missing`.

Also, note the distinction between public, protected and private methods (private and protected methods have limitations on who is allowed to call them).